# how to end a vb.net program at a certain time

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to auto-end a vb.net app? Let's say for 5 minutes it will kill its own process if it is not being used by the user or is passive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its an Winform, you can call Application.Exit() to end the program.

You can use a scheduler like [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) to do that or just use the "System.Timers.Timer" and build the expiration logic yourself.